# How to see if not colliding

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I want to see if a car that I have is not colliding with a rect. My car is on the road, and I don't want it to go off. So I want the computer to detect if the car is of the road, kind of like the colliderect() function, but the opposite. Here is my code: MY MISTAKE STUPID QUESTIN!!!!!!!!

```
import pygame    
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

#define variables
width, height = 940, 780
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
grey = 87, 87, 87
white = 255, 255, 255
player = pygame.image.load("Pics\goodcar.jpeg")
keys = [False, False, False, False, False]
playerpos = [0,40]
green = 0,255,0
red = 255,0,0
color = red

x1 = 0
x2 = 40
y1 = 940
y2 = 100




#main program

while 1:

    screen.fill(0)
    road = pygame.draw.rect(screen, grey, (x1,x2,y1,y2), 0)
    traffic_light = pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, (640,90), 40, 0)


    screen.blit(player, playerpos)



    car_rect = player.get_rect(left=playerpos[0], top=playerpos[1])






    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit(0)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_RIGHT:
                keys[0]=True
            if event.key==K_LEFT:
                keys[1]=True
            if event.key==K_DOWN:
                keys[2]=True
            if event.key==K_UP:
                keys[3]=True
            if event.key==K_SPACE:
                keys[4]=True



        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                keys[0]=False
            if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                keys[1]=False
            if event.key==pygame.K_DOWN:
                keys[2]=False
            if event.key==pygame.K_UP:
                keys[3]=False
            if event.key==pygame.K_SPACE:
                keys[4]=False

    if traffic_light.colliderect(car_rect):
        if color == red:
            keys[0]=False
    if car_rect == 100:
        keys[2]=False


    if keys[0]==True:
        playerpos[0]+=2
    if keys[1]==True:
        playerpos[0]-=2
    if keys[2]==True:
        playerpos[1]+=2
    if keys[3]==True:
        playerpos[1]-=2


    if keys[4]==True:
        if color==red:
            color = green
        else:
            color = red
    pygame.display.update()
```

thanks for the help in previous!

Comment: Umm... why not `if not colliderect(firstThing, secondThing):`?

Comment: Please show the code for your `colliderect()` method. Why all the blank lines in what you already have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `not` statement to do the opposite of `colliderect`:

```
if not thing1.colliderect(thing2):
    ....
```